# inferred type is DashboardFragment.Companion but Fragment was expected in function replaceFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

```
private val dashboardFragment = DashboardFragment
private val settingsFragment = SettingsFragment
private val infoFragment = InfoFragment

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityHomePageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding?.root)

    replaceFragment(dashboardFragment)

}

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    if(fragment != null){
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.frag_container, fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

I have 3 fragments setup in my project namely - Dashboard, settings and Info. I am getting an error for type mismatch everytime I enter my fragment name in the function replaceFragment. I am referring to this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8MbOjBCu0o&t=1s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate these fields . right now they r just pointing to the class type . Its similar to `new` keyword in java .

```
private val dashboardFragment = DashboardFragment()
private val settingsFragment = SettingsFragment()
private val infoFragment = InfoFragment()
```